# MATLAB as COM Automation Server with Javascript

Tags: javascript, matlab, typescript, com

I am trying to make a connection between Matlab and a Javascript (typescript in my case) program with a COM automation server as suggested on the MathWorks website. The docs on the website have examples for some languages created by MS, not for javascript.

I can't seem to find a lot of information on how to establish such a COM connection with JS. From what I've read, it's an old Microsoft feature that was only used with Internet Explorer.

**Problem**
The program I am writing is a VS Code extension, thus I am not using Internet Explorer at all. As a result, I do not believe I can use ActiveXObjects.

**Question**
Is there another way to establish a connection between my typescript code and the Matlab instance?

**Goal**
I am trying to run Matlab files from the VS Code terminal without opening a custom Matlab terminal or the complete Matlab GUI. The output should be displayed in the VS Code terminal as well. On MacOS and Linux, I can simply use the CLI tools, but due to the differences between the Windows version and MacOS/Linux versions, this is not possible on Windows.

Comment: If possible, consider adding the working example you have for MacOS/Linux. This is really helpful to make questions such as this useful for future users. Also provide the link to the Mathworks documentation you've mentioned.

Comment: What if you give up the COM path, and go with python? Is that acceptable?

Comment: @hackape I have to work with Javascript to create a VS Code plugin. The problem is that I can not use an ActiveXObject because, at least to my understanding, it is only used for Internet Explorer

Comment: Sorry, but I have zero knowledge about this COM/ActiveXObject thing. I see that you're the author of Matlab Code Run, checked the source code. The way I see it, you're really looking for a consistent cross-platform interface to interop between js and matlab. That's why I bring up python as an option.

Comment: And I don't think many people know about this COM thing. So my thought is, don't limit your options down to COM so early in your question. Also, I'm not sure what exactly is the difference btw linux/window CLI interface that's impossible to overcome even with some adapter/wrapper?

Comment: @hackape So the problem is that on Windows, Matlab can by itself not output to the terminal (cmd, Powershell). It uses a shell created in Java I believe from which I can not get the output. But apparently, Windows has this old feature for cross application communication which is what Matlab suggests to use for these kind of use cases. Unfortunately, it is not well documented... I am looking into using websockets though, but that would mean that the user has to start Matlab first to open the socket, which kinda defeats the purpose of the extension :/

Comment: Poor windows. Anyway, I'm pretty sure the COM path is a dead end. If I understand you right, the question title is not reflecting your real problem. Suggest rephrase to get valid answers.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used TypeScript very much, and what little I did, it was a long time ago when it was completely new.

However, the NPM  package win32ole can be used in NodeJS, so I would assume you would be able to use it in Typescript as well (perhaps with some minor modifications to the example, or a small wrapper).

[win32ole npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32ole)

This is an example from that page, showing how to interact with Excel to create and save a worksheet.

```
try{
  var win32ole = require('win32ole');
  // var xl = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application'); // You may write it as:
  var xl = win32ole.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application');
  xl.Visible = true;
  var book = xl.Workbooks.Add();
  var sheet = book.Worksheets(1);
  try{
    sheet.Name = 'sheetnameA utf8';
    sheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = 'test utf8';
    var rg = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, 2), sheet.Cells(4, 4));
    rg.RowHeight = 5.18;
    rg.ColumnWidth = 0.58;
    rg.Interior.ColorIndex = 6; // Yellow
    var result = book.SaveAs('testfileutf8.xls');
    console.log(result);
  }catch(e){
    console.log('(exception cached)\n' + e);
  }
  xl.ScreenUpdating = true;
  xl.Workbooks.Close();
  xl.Quit();
}catch(e){
  console.log('*** exception cached ***\n' + e);
}
```